# Python variables not importing properly

Tags: python, pip, environment-variables

In this code I'm importing the boto3 module but my problem obviously has nothing to do with the module.

From the terminal i can import my module but when run from a python script, it doesn't work correctly. I installed it with a simple pip install; I thought this is all i need to do for modules to work. I then checked the location of the module to make sure my python path includes that location. Why is this happening?

```
Luke-3589:~ luketimberlake$ pip install boto3
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1; python_version >= "2.7"->botocore<1.13.0,>=1.12.163->boto3) (1.12.0)

Luke-3589:~ luketimberlake$ python
Python 2.7.16 (default, Apr 12 2019, 15:32:52) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import inspect, boto3
>>> s3 = boto3.client('s3')
>>> inspect.getfile(boto3)
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/__init__.pyc'
>>> exit()

Luke-3589:~ luketimberlake$ echo $PYTHONPATH
:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3

Luke-3589:~ luketimberlake$ python Desktop/aws.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desktop/aws.py", line 1, in <module>
    import boto3
  File "/Users/luketimberlake/Desktop/boto3.py", line 3, in <module>
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'client'
```

Comment: You have file `boto3.py` in your current folder. You attempt to import _that_ file instead of the installed `boto3`. Rename that file.

Comment: According to [this page](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/636) you may have a file name that's conflicting with the module in the import process

Comment: The file is in `Desktop`, not in the current directory. It's `/Users/luketimberlake/Desktop/boto3.py`. Rename, move or remove it.

Comment: Ok this answers my question but i'm having the same problem when launching an app(This one doesnt have a .py that's named the same thing as the module). What might be the problem? I can import the module in the terminal but when launching the app, i get an error "ImportError: No module named protobuf"